# Import in a CSV and Exporting to a Text File

Tags: powershell

I been ting to research this and I'm trying to do something that I'm not sure is possible in Powershell.  I have a CSV like this with the header included:

```
Field1,Field2,Field3

Field1aaa,abc,rst

Field2bbb,ghi,xyz
```

In the end, I'm looking to take the CSV and export to a text file in a specific format. And it needs to be formatted this way for the program that I'm working with. It's kind of like a JSON file, but not quite. I'm trying to create essential a block of text for each CSV row. Here is what I'm literally trying to get on the output text file

```
   Fieldaaa {
       field2<abc>
       field3<rst>
   }
   Field2bbb {
       field2<ghi>
       field3<xyz>
```

Think of field1 like the title for each group as I listed above. I have accomplished loading in the csv:

```
$userobjects = Import-CSV C:\temp\testcsv2.csv.
```

But then I don't know how to do it from here. And to add, that text output I'm trying to add in are tab keys. I imagine I could do this by inserting in \t once I figure out how to parse this CSV and export to text. And I can use Powershell 5.1 as I'm working with Server 2016 and Windows 10 environment with that version. Please let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to follow these steps:

1. get the content (you already did this, and its already in a nice object for you to use)
2. Iterate around each row and append some formatted value to an output string
3. write that output string to your file

Here is one way you can do this:

```
$outString = ""
$userobjects = Import-CSV C:\test\test.csv

foreach ($object in $userobjects) {
    $outString = @"
$outString

$($object.Field1) {
    field2<$($object.Field2)>
    field3<$($object.Field3)>
}    
"@
}

Set-Content C:\test\out.txt $outString
```

Or maybe a more PowerShelly way is

```
Import-Csv C:\test\test.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Output @"
$($_.Field1) {
    field2<$($_.Field2)>
    field3<$($_.Field3)>
}
"@ } > c:\test\out.txt
```

If you don't know it already, I can recommend checking [ss64](https://ss64.com/ps/) for powershell examples

Comment: Thank you for your input. Both suggestions were extremely helpful. I didn't realize that Write-Output is what I need and I can see that the @" and the "@ set the beginning and end of the output. I am aware of SS64 and I did consult there when searching around. 

By the way, there is a typo on the second example of "Field3)".  There was a "t" added there. I tried editing your comment, but it said it needed to be more than 7 characters for some reason. Just adding that on here in case anyone looks at this example.  Thanks again for your help